# how to get the latest message from whatsapp web

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, bots, whatsapp

I am creating a js script for WhatsApp Web with which I want to respond to messages from a certain group.

my code:

```
  console.log('WhatsappWeb On');

function sleep(num){
    setTimeout(num);
}

var eventFire = (element, type) => {var MyEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");MyEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);element.dispatchEvent(MyEvent);};

var ValueNameForBot = '';
var WhatsappWeb = {
    OpenContact: function(name){
        ValueNameForBot = name;
        console.log(' abst.js [OpenContact: Open] -> ' + name);
        var element = document.querySelector('[title="' + name + '"]');
        var mouseEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        mouseEvent.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
    },

    SendMessage: function(message){
        WhatsappWeb.OpenContact(ValueNameForBot);
        console.log(' abst.js [SendMessage: Send] -> ' + message);
        var div = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable='true']")[1];
        div.innerHTML = message;
        var event = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
        event.initUIEvent("input", true, true, window, 1);
        div.dispatchEvent(event);
        eventFire(document.querySelector('span[data-icon="send"]'), 'click');
    },
    GetMessage: function(){
        // receive the last message
    }
};
```

usage example:

```
    WhatsappWeb.OpenContact('group');
 WhatsappWeb.SendMessage('Hi group');

  //with GetMessage
 // WHAT I WANT THE SCRIPT TO DO
  WhatsappWeb.OpenContact('GROUP');
var message = WhatsappWeb.GetMessage();
if(message == 'Hi bot'){
WhatsappWeb.SendMessage('Hi User');
}
```

this ran it in chrome/google.

¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

ahh
my mistake was in a '[]'

```
GetMessage: function(){
        sleep(1025);
        var MessageChat = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="_3-8er selectable-text copyable-text"] span')[document.querySelectorAll('span[class="_3-8er selectable-text copyable-text')["length"]-1];
        var MessageText = MessageChat.innerText;
        return MessageText;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please format your code nicely? Not only your answer, but also your question?